# Warning: exceptions.KeyError: u'Undefined namespace prefix: i18.'

Tags: plone, dexterity

I hit this error on our instance of Plone 4.3.2 by going to:

Site setup > Dexterity Content Types > (selecting a type) > Fields tab > Edit XML Model

Here's the full error:

```
We’re sorry, but there seems to be an error…

Here is the full error message:

Display traceback as text

Traceback (innermost last):

Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 70, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
Module Products.Five.browser.metaconfigure, line 479, in __call__
Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 125, in __call__
Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 59, in __call__
Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 126, in pt_render
Warning: Compilation failed
Warning: exceptions.KeyError: u'Undefined namespace prefix: i18.'
PTRuntimeError: ['Compilation failed', "exceptions.KeyError: u'Undefined namespace prefix: i18.'"]
```

I haven't been able to find something useful about this error on the web, but @eleddy mentioned it's a common Plone problem and all I need to do is upgrade something something to fix it. Anyone know what the "something something" is? Thanks!

If it's useful, here is what is currently installed on our Plone instance:

- Plone 4.3.2 (4307)
- CMF 2.2.7
- Zope 2.13.21
- Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar 9 2014, 22:15:05) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]
- PIL 1.7.8 (Pillow)

And add-ons...

- Content portlet 1.8.1
- ContentWellPortlets 4.2.1
- Dexterity Content Types 2.0.9
- Diazo theme support 1.1.1
- Dropdown menu 2.3.1
- FacultyStaffDirectory 3.1.3
- HTTP caching support 1.1.6
- Membrane: content-based users and groups 2.1.11
- Plone Classic Theme 1.3.2
- Plone JQuery Integration 1.7.2
- Plone JQuery Tools Integration 1.5.6
- Plone Keyword Manager 2.1
- Plone Quick Upload 1.6.5
- PloneFormGen 1.7.15
- Relations 0.9b1
- Twitter portlet 0.10
- jQuery UI 1.10.1.2
- plone.app.collection 1.0.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in Dexterity that was already fixed (https://github.com/plone/plone.app.dexterity/commit/4e3d4f8fa029662a089c3f01cf6401d34b84336e). Upgrading to plone.app.dexterity 2.0.11 should fix it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks again David! I ended up just upgrading the whole instance to Plone 4.3.3 because I hit a bunch of compatibility issues when just changing plone.app.dexterity to = 2.0.11 in versions.cfg. Works fine now though. :)

Comment: Quick question: after following these upgrade directions (https://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide/minor-version-upgrades) by uncommenting http://dist.plone.org/release... and then commenting versions.cfg — do I then need to download that versions.cfg and replace my local versions.cfg with it? (i.e. so if I ever run buildout again?)

Comment: No -- you commented out versions.cfg, so buildout is not going to use it any more. You *could* do that (and switch back to having versions.cfg uncommented and dist.plone.org commented) if you don't want to be as reliant on plone.org when running buildout.

Comment: Okay gotcha, makes sense. Thanks again David!